# Javascript throws typeerror on ios only

Tags: javascript, php, ios, dom

I have a strange problem and I bet it is just a really stupid error somewhere, but I just can't figure out, what's wrong with my code..

I have a website that works perfectly fine on every (common) browser on every common os.
On this page i have a searchbar, which also works perfectly fine on computer. This bar also has a jquery keyup event, to start the search.
This event does not fire on ios (first problem). So I added a button as workaround. But this also doesn't work on ios.
If it would work correctly, it should call a JS-Method that only redirects the user to the search.php page while appending a GET-Variable called query. I loaded the page on pc and the error console says:

TypeError:  is not a function (evaluating 'search()')

It somehow does not seem to load this method. For whatever reason. All other JS-Methods work fine. Just this one refuses to work.

The searchbar:

```
<input placeholder="Search" id="searchbar">
```

the link looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="searchbutton" onclick="search();">start search</a>
```

The JS-Method looks like this:

```
var text = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
window.location.href="./search.php?q="+text;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems global variable `search` is reserved by iOS. Try to use some another name like `mySearch` then it works.

BTW, you may consider using namespace or scope to avoid conflict with libraries or system.

**Example:**

```
(function() {
    function search() {
       alert('test');
    }
    document.getElementById('searchbutton').onclick = search;
})();
```

Or if you insist to use `onclick` directly in the element.

```
<a href="#" id="searchbutton" onclick="MyNamespace.search();">start search</a>

<script>
var MyNamespace = (function() {
    function search() {
       alert('test');
    }
    return {
        search: search
    };
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it and it solved a part of my problem, but I found the solution myself. Thanks for your hint! This helped me solving the problem!
The problem was simply a name. The mobile search bar had the same ID as the desktop search bar (actually I copied the innerHTML of the desktop search to the mobile div).
By clearing the desktop search afterwards the problem was gone. Such a simple (logical) mistake held me up for hours. This was a bit embarrassing.